# OpenCV Assertion Error when converting image to greyscale

Tags: python, opencv

When trying to convert an image to grey scale in opencv I get the following error message which can be seen here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9C3kg.png

Here's the code:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('pictures\chessBoard.png',0)
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

These error messages are pretty cryptic, especially to someone new to opencv. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the 0 flag in imread forces your image into grayscale already, thus the later conversion fails.

so either skip the conversion:

```
gray_image = cv2.imread('pictures\chessBoard.png',0)
cv2.imshow('image',gray_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
...
```

or read a bgr image, and convert later

```
img = cv2.imread('pictures\chessBoard.png')
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('image',gray_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

just as a reminder, here are the imread() flags again :

```
>>> help(cv2)
...
IMREAD_ANYCOLOR = 4
IMREAD_ANYDEPTH = 2
IMREAD_COLOR = 1
IMREAD_GRAYSCALE = 0
IMREAD_LOAD_GDAL = 8
IMREAD_UNCHANGED = -1
...
```

Comment: @seat3542 Make sure to mark this as the solution since it worked.